# Wrong location for css/js/img folders after having implemented language folders

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, directory

So I decided to create a site with two languages. I created two folders. One folder for English and one for Spanish. The structure is like that:

```
img
css
js
en/home.html
es/home.html
```

When the user selects to change language from the dropdown menu, he is being redirected to the according folders. However when the `/en/home` or `/es/home` is accessed the content inside css, js and img folders is not loading because the website is searching to the wrong directory. For example, it is searching to `/en/css/custom.css` which ofcourse doesn't exists.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to change the `href` element in the `link` tag.  The `../` will move up one directory and then search for a directory called `css` within that directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```